# propel:retrieve database data and displaying them

Tags: propel

i am working with propel for the first time. OK!!. i am able to get the database values using this code

```
$rolesname = RolesQuery::create()->find();
```

ok now i am trying to display them using the following code

```
<select name="designationType" id="designation">
  <option>----select----</option>
  <?php
    foreach($rolesname as $role){
        echo "<option value='".$role."'>".$role->roleName."</option>";  
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

all what am getting is the entire table contains in this pattern

1. Roleid:1 RoleName:Admin
2. RoleId:2 RoleName:office
3. RoleId:3 RoleName:Headman
4. RoleId:4 RoleName:Terac

i want to be able to display only the Rolename in the select field. please how can i retrieve only the RoleName? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your roles are propel object and you should use the get methods instead of trying to access the properties directly, your echo line should look something like this:

`echo "<option value='".$role->getRoleId()."'>".$role->getRoleName()."</option>";`